# Getting access to a Stack Exchange user's `about_me` data via API?

Tags: stackexchange-api

I'm trying to get the `about_me` data on Stack Exchange profiles via the API provided by Stack Overflow using: https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users-by-ids.

Example:
    https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users/3029?&site=bitcoin

The API doesn't return the `about_me` profile description.
How does one get access to this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`about_me` property is not returned by default](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/user); you must use [a custom filter](https://stackapps.com/a/4491/7653) to get it.

For example:
    [/2.2/users/1642231?site=stackoverflow&filter=!eQnjl7OMkDx5MiwVw_4HYqq7h5](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/users-by-ids#order=desc&sort=reputation&ids=1642231&filter=!eQnjl7OMkDx5MiwVw_4HYqq7h5&site=stackoverflow&run=true)

Which currently returns:

```js
"items": [ {
    "down_vote_count":  11,
    "up_vote_count":    66,
    "reputation":       7912,
    "user_id":          1642231,
    "accept_rate":      83,
    "about_me":         "<p>Stanford graduate female developer living and working...",
    "display_name":     "Patoshi パトシ"
    //etc...
```

Comment: how do u even get that custom filter in the  first place?

Comment: Follow [the link](https://stackapps.com/a/4491/7653) in the answer; it shows the process.